# Can I change an object on a sleeping thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

**Scenario**

There is a factory that receives orders. Once received, every order item goes through a multi-step production process. Every step is done by a separate machine and every machine can only handle one item at a time. So the order comes in, the first item goes to machine1, when it's done it goes to machine2 and the next item to machine1, etc.

**Technical part**

Every machine is implemented as a thread and has a queue with all items lined up that need this step of the process next. The run method of the machine checks in an endless while loop if there is anything in the queue, if yes it will handle that item, `sleep` for a certain amount of time and then push the item to the queue of the next machine.

**Questions**

In my head, this sounds all pretty simple. But I constantly run into null-pointer errors and other weird exceptions. I honestly don't fully understand what's wrong but I suspect it's a problem with multi-threading vs. sleep. At this point I got two questions:

1. What happens if I call a method of a sleeping thread (machine)? (Example: I call `machine.addItemToQueue()` while that machine is working on another item).
2. Follows Q1: Let's say I really can't call that method while the machine 'sleeps'. How else would I handle this? Should I take the queue outside the machine? Is this an async problem?

Comment: A thread which is asleep is one which is not doing any processing.  Objects don't live on threads, they live in memory.  So you can modify an object from any thread and when the sleeping thread wakes up, it will be able to read those changes (there's some discussion about how the memory model works and when writes become available, but I'm trying to keep it simple).  Essentially what you're discussing is a "producer/consumer" workflow.  Order -> M1 -> M2 -> and so on.  Yes, if a machine is takes longer to operate, it will either need to "block" the entire chain or queue the result

Comment: @MadProgrammer So, if I understand you correctly, I should be perfectly able to call `machine.addItemToQueue()` while that machine is asleep? When it wakes up its queue would just be +1 item in the queue. I'm fine with it "blocking" the other items, that's how the process should work. The issue is that I run into weird things like items "jumping over" a machine step when it's sleeping.

Comment: So, I would imagine that you would have some sort of "lock" mechanism, which would prevent new work from been added to a machine until the machine is ready, this would mean that "add work" would block the thread from other machine, till the thread which is processing the machines work is done.  This way, no machine could accept new work till the current work is done. Alternatively, you could queue the work for each machine (ie a storage space, either with limited or unlimited storage), which would prevent a "fast" process from been blocked (until the next step runs of storage) - up to you

Comment: @user16320675 OK! I haven't heard of `BlockingQueue` yet, but if it allows for items to be added to the queue and only passes on one at a time, it sounds like a potentially great solution.

To clarify: If I understand you correctly, I would **not** be able to call `machine.addItemToQueue()` while that machine is asleep?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Ok, this made it more clear for me. I think a problem might have been that I wanted the queue to be "in" the machine. So the machine knows all the lined up items and just runs through them one at a time. But based on your input, it might really be smarter to solve the whole queueing problem outside of the machine and just add it when it's ready again.

Comment: @MichaBrugger Yes and no, but it will depend on your needs.  I would create a queue.  This could be passed to the the previous machine (as the output) and the next machine (as the input), for example.  So as M1 produces work, it pushes it onto the "output" and when M2 is ready, it pops of the next item when it's ready.  You could still have each machine have it's own "in" queue if you wanted, but what you need to realise is that the just because M2 might be "asleep", the queue is still writable by other threads (assuming access is available) - this is how a blocking queue works

Comment: You might also want to look into an actor model implementation such as Akka.io. It implements a design very similar to this, but more efficiently (not requiring one thread per object).